# Summing columns of a txt file in java

Tags: java

I have a text file that reads:

1 2 3 4 5

6 7 8 9 1

8 3 9 7 1

9 3 4 8 2

8 7 1 6 5

where each number is separated by a tab.

My question is, is there a simple way to sum the columns of numbers using java? I want it to sum 1+6+8+9+8, 2+7+3+3+7, etc. I am reading the file using:

```
 public static boolean testMagic(String pathName) throws IOException {
    // Open the file
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathName));

    // For each line in the file ...
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // ... sum each column of numbers
        }

    reader.close();
    return isMagic;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String[] fileNames = { "MyFile.txt" };
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is the number of columns known or variable? You can just create an array of sums and parse each line into ints and the add it to the correct sum.

```
// For each line in the file ...
String line;
int sums[5]; //Change to the number of columns
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String tokens[] = line.split("\t");
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
       sums[i] += Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
    }
 }
```

If you don't know the number of columns beforehand use an `ArrayList` and do the first line differently so that you can figure out the number of columns.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a dumb question but its my first day using java. I would like to test my code on other txt files so the number of columns isn't a known variable. I've been reading about ArrayList but haven't been able to implement one successfully. What do you mean by "do the first line differently"?

Comment: Never mind I figured it out. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In the `while`-loop split the String (sepated with `\t`) and than parse the `int`values.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to parse numbers from a text file is with [`java.util.Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class Summer {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws Exception
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
        }
    }
}
```

Since you want to sum up line-by-line, you could use two scanners:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Summer {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws Exception
    {
        /* List to hold sums */
        ArrayList<Integer> sums = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Scanner sc_file = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
        while (sc_file.hasNextLine()) {
            Scanner sc_line = new Scanner(sc_file.nextLine());

            /* Process each column within the line */
            int column = 0;
            while (sc_line.hasNext()) {
                /* When in column n, make sure list has at least n entries */
                if (column >= sums.size()) {
                    sums.add(0);
                }
                sums.set(column, sums.get(column) + sc_line.nextInt());
                column++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(sums);
    }
}
```